# Plutus Playground Client fails to load: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: plutus

```
$ nix --version
nix (Nix) 2.5.1

$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4.20210212

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 21.10 \n \l
```

I have the plutus playground server running inside a nix-shell in another terminal:

```
$ netstat -natlp | grep plutus
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3772215/plutus-play
```

Then i get into another nix-shell, cd to the plutus-playground-client (i already did git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a) and run `npm start` or `npm run start`

This is what i'm getting anyway:

```
16:33 :) ../plutus-playground-client # npm start

> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start /home/atcasanova/plutus/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client
> plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev

[Info] Running: (Nothing,PSGenerator {_outputDir = "generated"})
The following purescript packages are needed by the generated code:

  - plutus-playground-client
  - purescript-argonaut-codecs
  - purescript-either
  - purescript-enums
  - purescript-lists
  - purescript-maybe
  - purescript-newtype
  - purescript-ordered-collections
  - purescript-prelude
  - purescript-profunctor-lenses
  - purescript-tuples
  - web-common

Successfully created your PureScript modules!

Successfully created your servant API purescript functions!
Please make sure you have purescript-servant-support and purescript-bridge-json-helpers installed

plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [RawError "/nix/store/xvj7mn015p98yypgwvzk4cq31b9j5xq7-plutus-ledger-constraints-lib-plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/libHSplutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0-EN1avZ1OL0p63dNgqFuLBm-ghc8.10.4.20210212.so: undefined symbol: plutuszmledgerzmapizm0zi1zi0zi0zmKIxxnVyHrLq1ei02VYnb9P_PlutusziV1ziLedgerziBytes_zdwzdcshowsPrec_info\n"]))
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-13T19_34_10_171Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's fixed.

At first i was running the ubuntu-packed version of nix-bin, which was 2.3.10.
I then downloaded the newest version of nix following [these instructions](https://nixos.org/download.html).

After loading the new version (since i've installed it with the --no-daemon flag i had to load a shell script) it kept malfunctioning. Then another user on the discord channel told me it would be nice to do a garbage collect and rebuild the server since i changed versions.

```
nix-collect-garbage
nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
```

It took a few hours but when it was done i've got everything running.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to overcome this issue by running `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start`.

Comment: What exactly that means?

Comment: Can you make this answer more clear and explicit?  We are catering to varied skill levels and many visitors whose native language is not English.  The few extra minutes it takes to make the answer clear and precise benefits everybody.

Comment: It will also make it more likely that @alfredo will mark it as the accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have purescript-servant-support and purescript-bridge-json-helpers installed

Have you tried installing those ?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the commit from the setup guide *41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a*. Using different commit worked for me. You can try `git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd`.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].