# How to resolve npm build failure after running `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start`?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

MacOs Catalina 10.15.7 (Intel)

After facing issue [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/plutus-playground-client-fails-to-load/6451#6451), I ran the command `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm run start` and it build some libraries, however failed with following error (plutus-playground-server was up and running):

```
79 silly inflate node_modules/@xtuc/ieee754
80 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fleb128 119ms (cache revalidated)
81 silly inflate node_modules/@xtuc/long
2686 error                         ^
2686 error ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
2686 error         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
2686 error              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2686 error                         &
2686 error 2 warnings generated.
2686 error In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
2686 error In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56:
2686 error In file included from /Users/CrosbyTop/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/node.h:63:
2686 error In file included from /Users/CrosbyTop/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/v8.h:25:
2686 error In file included from /Users/CrosbyTop/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12:
2686 error In file included from /Users/CrosbyTop/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:12:
2686 error /Users/CrosbyTop/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:566:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
2686 error             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
2686 error                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
2686 error                                      remove_cv
2686 error /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:697:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
2686 error template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
2686 error                                                  ^
2686 error 1 error generated.
2686 error make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
2686 error gyp ERR! build error
2686 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
2686 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/CrosbyTop/projects/cardano/ppp3/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
2686 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
2686 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
2686 error gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
2686 error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.0.1/bin/node" "/Users/CrosbyTop/projects/cardano/ppp3/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
2686 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/CrosbyTop/projects/cardano/ppp3/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/node-sass
2686 error gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.1
2686 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
2686 error gyp ERR! not ok
2686 error Build failed with error code: 1
2687 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

Actually, changing `node-sass` version to `^7.0.0` inside package-json helped me, however I am not sure it did not break any dependencies.
Node 17+ is not supported by node-sass ^5.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

It also helped me to run the server with that prefix as well:

```
cd plutus-playground-server
GC_DONT_GC=1 plutus-playground-server
```

I used setup instructions from here and it worked for me: https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md